# htaccess redirect rules don't work

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm new to htaccess so don't judge me please :).
I have the following problem - I'm making a website in my local server /it's apache2/ and the project is located in the www/html/subFolder/MVC.
In the MVC folder I have the following structure

```
MVC
|-- .htaccess
|-- app
||-- bootstrap.php
||-- .htaccess
||-- config
||-- controllers
||-- helpers
||-- libraries
|||-- controller.php
|||-- core.php
||`-- database.php
||-- models
|`-- views
`-- public
|-- .htaccess
|-- css
|-- img
|-- index.php
`-- js
```

The problem is that I try to make a redirect rule for the public folder. For example when the user try to open MVC/public/test.php /some file that doesn't exist/ it should redirect it to the MVC/public/index.php, but my rule doesn't work
Here is my htaccess file in the public folder

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 Options -Multiviews
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /MVC/public
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

And here is my htaccess in the root folder

```
﻿<IfModule>
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteRule ^& public/ [L]
 RewriteRule (.*) public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the main config for apache I didn't allowed to override my htaccess files. I just add a rule for that O

```
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
AllowOverride all
```

And it's all working now